# Generate static analysis output in XML format using findbugs

Tags: java, build, static-analysis, findbugs, devops

I want to use findbugs to do static analysis on java programs. However, I do not want to use the eclipse GUI. I want to run it from command line and generate the static analysis output using findbugs.jar in a format such as XML or json. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using Maven in this project as well? There's actually a FindBugs plugin that will produce XML for you.

Comment: yes. I am using maven in this project.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Maven, give the [FindBugs plugin](http://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/index.html) a try. It is capable of generating an [XML report](http://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/examples/findbugs.xml) as part of your build process

Comment: is it possible to run a FindBugs plugin without maven?

Comment: Specifically without maven or without a build tool in general? There is also an ant plugin, and a whole install process for just FindBugs, but I have never tried either of them: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/anttask.html and http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/running.html